# Cannot set global variable in postman script

Tags: postman

When I log in to a Fortinet device via API, It returns a variable called fpc-sid.  This is their version of an authtoken.

When I attempt to put this on a global variable on the test section in the login request it returns the `fpc-sid` and then I get:

```sh
"ReferenceError: sid is not defined"
```

For some reason, I think it doesn't like the "-", but not sure.

How can I set fps-sid as a global variable?

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("fpc-sid", jsonData.fpc-sid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("fpc-sid", jsonData.fpc-sid);
```

Property cannot be accessed like that when it is not a valid identifier. use it by name as :

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("fpc-sid", jsonData['fpc-sid']);
```

Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Also use the pm object `pm.globals.set()` for setting variable as Danny mentioned. This is the new syntax, this will make it more future proof

Comment: Lets suggest using the newer Postman `pm.*` syntax -  `pm.response.json()` and `pm.globals.set()`, rather than the older syntax.